# Is it unique when a irreducible and aperiodic markov chain on general space has an invariant measure?

Tags: markov-chains

Recently I'm reading *Markov chains and Stochastics Stability(sencond edition 2009)* written by Meyn and Tweedie. And in the proof of Theorem 10.4.5 on page 243, it says "if $\pi_m$ is invariant for the $m$-skeleton then by aperiodicity the measure is the unique invariant measure(up to multiples) for $\Phi^m$." is that right? If not, is there any counter-example?

Here is the Theorem 10.4.5:

*Suppose that Markov Chain $\Phi$ is $\psi$-irreducible and aperiodic. Then, for each $m$, a measure $\pi$ is invariant for the $m$-skeleton if and only if it is invariant for $\Phi$.*

Comment: What's $m$-skeleton?

Comment: $\Phi_0, \Phi_m, \Phi_{2m}, \Phi_{3m}, ...$ picked out from the original chain